# Create a BCEL JavaClass object from arbitrary .class file

Tags: java, bytecode, bcel

I'm playing around with BCEL.  I'm not using it to generate bytecode, but instead I'm trying to inspect the structure of existing compiled classes.

I need to be able to point to an arbitrary .class file anywhere on my hard drive and load a [JavaClass](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/JavaClass.html) object based on that.  Ideally I'd like to avoid having to add the given class to my classpath.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The straightforward way is to create a ClassParser with the file name and call parse(). Alternatively you can use SyntheticRepository and supply a classpath (that is not your classpath, IYSWIM).

Answer (score 3):

The existing .class can be class loaded to java lang class object. Then it can be converted into BCEL intermediate javaclass structure. The following code may help:-

```
Class<?> javaClass1 = null;
javaClass1 = ucl.loadClass("com.sample.Customer");
org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass javaClazz1=org.apache.bcel.Repository.lookupClass(javaClass1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new ClassParser(classfilebytearrayhere).parse()
```